# ImageIO.write freezes after a while

Tags: java

I have the following code which generates an image that is used as a src of an image element in an html document:

```
BufferedImage iImage = (BufferedImage) camera.getImage();
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
ImageIO.write(iImage, "jpg", ios);
ios.close();
out.close();
```

The application is deployed on apache tomcat. The problem is the image is freezing after a while, I think that it is because of ImageIO.write, I have tried to use

```
ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
```

but with no success.

My question is, is there an alternative?, why ImageIO is freezing?, what can I do to prevent it from freezing?

Comment: What would happen if you tried writing your image to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then the `byte[]` to your `ServletOutputStream`? Does it freeze while writing to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` or while writing to the `ServletOutputStream`?

Comment: Can you `strace` the process to see what is going on? Can you attach a java debugger to it?